# How to enable the save button for a form group on a filtered mat-table in angular when form group gets dirty?

Tags: angular, formarray, material-table, formgroups

I have a mat-table with related FormArray and I want to enable the save button on a form when it gets dirty.

If form is not filtered every thing works fine. But when I filter table's rows. The index changes but the buttons keep the binding to initial form index. Then is enabled the wrong button or no button.

You can see the behavior here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uyezen

Any help is appreciate to get this working.

Comment: You can do 2 things either check is dirty by id or filter FormArrayData same as u did for table while checking is dirty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that in a table you iterating through persons array, but in mat cells you are watching a form group name by index. and when you rendering only filtered persons in a table your form array dont know anything about it. it still watches its own array which is not filtered and its own index. http://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pg1wvb - here is the possible workaround.

Comment: Thanks, for your comments. Based in your answer I created a datasource from formArray. And everything now is working as it should. In case someone else have same issue can find solution here: (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vivfar)